# Ignore certain values from a file in Java

Tags: java, io

My content data in Notepad is `1 to 25`. How can I display the data that is marked in red below. The other values can be ignored.

[image]

Comment: This isn't clear enough. What rule are you using to select those values? Did you mean 1 to 5, then 11 to 15, then 21 to 25? In other words, select five, then skip five, then select five, and so on?

Comment: Please copy-paste your code here instead of posting screenshots

Comment: i do not understand much about coding, because i am new programmer.... :(

Comment: @rickyhitman10 The two previous comments weren't about coding, but about how to improve your question so that someone can answer it.

Comment: @rickyhitman10 , I meant in the question ,not as a comment!

Comment: 'Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
  sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
  while (sc.hasNext()){
   int i=sc.nextInt();
  System.out.print(i+" ");
   }
  
  sc.close();
 }
}'

Comment: @rickyhitman10 , -_- Did you read my second comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
int i = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(i + " ");
```

to

```
int i = sc.nextInt();
if(i%10 <= 5) {
      System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

Idea is that `i%10` will give the unit digit of a number. So if  it is `<=` 5 print that number.

Comment: if this is the pattern, actually we don't know. But you can change this easily for every other pattern.

Comment: @johny yeah it is very probable that this is the pattern, but we can not say without knowing it. (and for this example you're completly right)